# Java GUI mouse cursor

Tags: java, swing

Okay so, I have this function which I call on every JButton I create, and it works fine.

```
public void addcursor(JButton button)
{
    button.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
            ButtonModel model=(ButtonModel) e.getSource();
            if(model.isRollover())                  
                setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));              
            else
                setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        }
    });
}
```

However, this code works only when I move over a JButton, and sets the mouse cursor back to default when I move away from the Button. So, on a separate class/function:

```
gui.getRootPane().setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
gui.getRootPane().setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
```

After calling those 2 functions, the first function addcursor(JButton) doesn't work anymore, I just want to set the buttons getModel back to how it was, after setting the cursor back to default. Note that I also tried re-calling the addcursoor(JButton) function after setting the crusor to default, but it still didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just set cursors directly to the jbuttons? Why monitor its model, and changing the global cursor? This may cause your conflicting cursor setting problem.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components already support a cursor that will change on a mouse entered event:

```
button.setCursor( Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

The cursor will also reset on a mouse exited event. So you don't need any special logic to support this type of functionality.

```
setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
```

I've always just used `setCursor(null)` when doing manual manipulation of the cursor.

Comment: Much easier than the whole function that I was using, thanks alot.